# C++ Boost Asio SSL, data always encrypted?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio

I'm trying to write program to communicate with a server.
I'm using C++, boost::asio, TCP and OpenSSl to send and receive message.

- C++ : 20
- Boost : 1.78
- OpenSSL : 1.1.1p
- Windows
- Visual Studio 2022

My problem is that the messages received are always encrypted.
I can not read it correctly.
Does not boost automatically solve the encryption ?

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    #pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#endif

#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#if defined(_WIN32)
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <wincrypt.h>
#endif


using boost_query    = boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query;
using boost_resolver = boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver;
using boost_endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint;
using boost_context  = boost::asio::ssl::context;
using boost_socket   = boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>;
using boost_error    = boost::system::errc::errc_t;

constexpr std::uint32_t MAX_BUFFER_RECV{ 1024u };

boost::system::error_code ec{};
boost::asio::io_service   ioService{};
boost_context             context{ boost_context::tlsv12 };
boost_socket              socketSSL{ ioService, context };
char                      recvBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_RECV]{ 0, };
std::string               host{};
std::int32_t              port{};
bool                      isSecu{};


static bool onVerifySSL(
    bool preverified,
    boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& verifyContext)
{
    char subjectName[256]{};
    auto* cert{
        X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(verifyContext.native_handle()) };
    if (nullptr == cert)
    {
        std::cerr << "Certificat is uncorrect." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    auto x509Name{ X509_get_subject_name(cert) };
    auto name{ X509_NAME_oneline(x509Name, subjectName, 256) };

    if (nullptr != name)     { std::cout << "certificat: " << name << std::endl;   }

    return true;
}


static void onSend(
    boost::system::error_code const& ec,
    std::size_t bytes)
{
    std::cout << "Sent : " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    if (boost_error::success == ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Sent success !" << std::endl;
    }
}


static void onReceive(
    boost::system::error_code const& ec,
    std::size_t bytes)
{
    std::cout << "Receive : " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    if (boost_error::success == ec)
    {
        char rxBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_RECV]{};
        std::memset(rxBuffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER_RECV);
        std::memcpy(rxBuffer, recvBuffer, bytes);
        std::cout
            << "Receive " << bytes << " bytes\n"
            << "data[" << rxBuffer << "]\n"
            << "data[";
        for (auto i{ 0 }; i < bytes; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << rxBuffer[i];
        }
        std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
        std::memset(recvBuffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER_RECV);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Fail receive" << std::endl;
    }
}


static void asyncRead()
{
    socketSSL.next_layer().async_receive(
        boost::asio::buffer(recvBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_RECV),
        boost::bind(
            onReceive,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}


static void asyncWrite()
{
    boost::json::object root;
    root["id"] = 1;
    root["method"] = "mining.subscribe";
    root["params"] = boost::json::array{ "Test/1.0", "EthereumStratum/1.0.0" };

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << root;
    std::string str{ oss.str() + "\n" };

    socketSSL.next_layer().async_send(
        boost::asio::buffer(str.c_str(), str.size()),
        boost::bind(
            &onSend,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}


static bool applySecu()
{
    if (false == isSecu)
    {
        socketSSL.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
        return true;
    }

    socketSSL.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    socketSSL.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(
            &onVerifySSL,
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2));

#if defined(_WIN32)
    auto certStore{ CertOpenSystemStore(0, "ROOT") };
    if (certStore == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Certifcat Store \"ROOT\" was nout found !" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    auto* store{ X509_STORE_new() };
    PCCERT_CONTEXT certContext{ nullptr };
    while (nullptr != (certContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(certStore, certContext)))
    {
        auto* x509
        {
            d2i_X509
            (
                nullptr,
                (const unsigned char**)&(certContext->pbCertEncoded),
                certContext->cbCertEncoded
            )
        };
        if (nullptr != x509)
        {
            X509_STORE_add_cert(store, x509);
            X509_free(x509);
        }
    }

    CertFreeCertificateContext(certContext);
    CertCloseStore(certStore, 0);

    SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(context.native_handle(), store);
#endif

    return true;
}


static bool resolveHost()
{
    auto const address{ boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host, ec) };
    if (boost_error::success != ec)
    {
        std::cout << "resolving " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
        boost_resolver resolver{ ioService };
        boost_query    query{ host, std::to_string(port) };
        auto           endpoints{ resolver.resolve(query, ec) };
        if (boost_error::success != ec)
        {
            std::cerr << "can not resolve " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        boost::asio::connect(socketSSL.next_layer(), endpoints, ec);
        if (boost_error::success != ec)
        {
            std::cerr << "can not connect to " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        boost_endpoint endpoint{
            address,
            static_cast<boost::asio::ip::port_type>(port) };
        socketSSL.next_layer().connect(endpoint, ec);
        if (boost_error::success != ec)
        {
            std::cerr << "can not connect to " << host << ":" << port << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


static bool connectToServer()
{
    std::cout << "Connection with " << host << ":" << port << " was etablished" << std::endl;
    socketSSL.next_layer().set_option(
        boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive(true));
    socketSSL.next_layer().set_option(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

    if (true == isSecu)
    {
        std::cout << "handshake" << std::endl;
        socketSSL.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, ec);
        if (boost_error::success != ec)
        {
            std::cerr << "Fail handshake" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr << "USAGE : ./pool_client <IP|DNS> <PORT> <IS_SECU>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    host.assign(argv[1]);
    port = std::atoi(argv[2]);
    isSecu = (std::atoi(argv[3]) == 1);

    std::cout
        << "Starting Tool Pool Client" << "\n"
        << "Connection " << host << ":" << port << "\n"
        << "SSL : " << std::boolalpha << isSecu << std::noboolalpha << std::endl;

    if (false == applySecu()) { return 1; }
    resolveHost();
    if (false == connectToServer()) { return 1; }
    asyncWrite();
    asyncRead();

    auto runService = boost::thread{
        boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService) };
    runService.join();

    return 0;
}
```

`tool_pool_client rvn.2miners.com 6060 0`
Output :
When I run my programm without SSL I can read the data received.

```
Starting Tool Pool Client
Connection rvn.2miners.com:6060
SSL : false
resolving rvn.2miners.com:6060
Connection with rvn.2miners.com:6060 was etablished
Sent : Operation success
Sent success !
Receive : Operation success
Receive 49 bytes
data[{"id":1,"result":["00f59158","6a"],"error":null}
]
data[{"id":1,"result":["00f59158","6a"],"error":null}
]
```

When I run my program with SSL I can not read the data received `data[]`.
`tool_pool_client rvn.2miners.com 16060 1`
Output :

```
Starting Tool Pool Client
Connection rvn.2miners.com:16060
SSL : true
resolving rvn.2miners.com:16060
Connection with rvn.2miners.com:16060 was etablished
handshake
certificat: /C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
certificat: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
certificat: /CN=*.2miners.com
Sent : Operation success
Sent success !
Receive : Operation success
Receive 62 bytes
data[§♥♥]
data[§♥♥→☺▀ò¡7%█¬Ø[▄>ÿ┤╔æ¢ÂD§♥♥→☻É8fÒl«ªé6í┐ýZ→å{<»]
```

The function `applySecu` add the certificas on the context.
The function `onReceive` print the data received.

What is my misstake ? Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: No, what made you think that Boost might have a complete implementation of a huge pile of cryptography-related protocols, did you see anything like that in Boost's documentation? Looks like the code that's not shown is not doing something correctly.

Comment: @user253751 i link the code : http://pastebin.fr/107966
The function `onReceive` print the data received.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I given parameters at boost, set the context with certificats in the function `applySecu` so for me boost does the job automatically.
Send with ecnryption and decode the data received.

I read some exemples to implement SSL but I haven't seen an example that explicitly describes the encryption and decryption step.
So for me boost does it on its own.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: `socketSSL.next_layer().async_receive` means you are asking to receive data directly from the socket without decrypting it

Comment: I don't see some flags or function to specify i want boost unencrypt the data received.
Do you have an exemple or documentation to specify it ?

Comment: @s4oul boost won't decrypt your data. That's more of a job for openssl.

Comment: `next_layer()` says to access the socket directly. What happens if you don't use it?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe wrong. Look at the fact `boost::asio::ssl::stream` is being used.

Comment: @user253751 If I don't user `next_lyaer` I can't call the function `async_receive`, `async_send`.

Comment: @s4oul That's right! What *are* the SSL send and receive functions named? It's a great mystery - maybe you can look up some information about `boost::asio::ssl::stream` on the Internet

Comment: There is not specific function to send or receive message with SSL.
In the official documentation https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp  `async_write` and `async_read` used, of course i also tested with them.

Comment: so it does. But the example is using `boost::asio::async_read(socket_,` and you are using `socket_.async_receive(` - is there a difference?

Comment: `socketSSL.next_layer().async_receive` give me data whereas `boost::asio::async_read` give me an error.
`tlsv1 alert protocol version (SSL routines, ssl3_read_bytes)`

Comment: @user253751 Thank you ! I replaced all `next_layer().async_X` by `boost::asio::async_` and use `boost::asio::streambuf` to send and receive data. Nos the data are decrypt correctly !

Comment: @user253751 I commend your Socratic patience here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socketSSL.next_layer()` means the actual socket, bypassing the SSL decoder. `socketSSL.next_layer().async_receive(...)` means to receive some data on the actual socket, bypassing the SSL decoder.

To get decoded SSL data you use `socketSSL` instead of `socketSSL.next_layer()`. `socketSSL.async_receive(...)` doesn't work, but [`socketSSL.async_read_some(...)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html) does, and the examples you read show `boost::asio::async_read(socketSSL, ...)` which also works.

Comment: I would phrase "To get decoded SSL data" with "to operate on the application stream" because you're not so much "decoding SSL data" as well as consuming the original stream - after it may have been transparently encoded/encrypted a number of times in transit)